# php direct path file_exists()

Tags: php, file

I'm using file_exists() in a class and I want to use it on the root as well as when included in another folder to see if a file exists.

I currently have:

```
if (file_exists("./photos/".$this->id.".jpg") ){ 

//

}
```

It works when included in the root but not when included in a folder (for ajax).

What can I do to make it direct (I think thats the correct word)? I am unable to put my site URL into it because of the nature of the function.

Comment: i have this structure:  /classes/class.php    and  /photos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use an absolute *(full)* path :

```
if (file_exists("/full/path/to/photos/".$this->id.".jpg") ){ 
    //
}
```

This way, no matter from where your script is executed, the full path, that will never change, will always work.

Of course, you probably don't want to hard-code the full path into your PHP script...

So you can use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the full path to the directory which contains the file into which you wrote that `dirname(__FILE__)`, and, from there, go with a relative one.

For example :

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../files/photos/'.$this->id.".jpg";
if (file_exists($path)) {
    // 
}
```

*(while testing this, you might want to display the value of `$path`, first, to make sure you got the path right)*

Note : if you are working with PHP >= 5.3, you can use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Relevant manual pages :

- [**`dirname()`**](http://www.php.net/dirname)
- [**`Magic constants`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php), including `__DIR__` and `__FILE__`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to put the full path from the root directory into the code.

```
if (file_exists("/root_dir/path/to/photos/".$this->id.".jpg") )
```

Comment: How do I find out this path? Thanks

Comment: Just log into your server via ssh or ftp, traverse to the webroot and that is where your path should start.  So if your webroot is "public_html" (common among most hosts), your path would begin with a / to dictate that you are starting from the root directory.  So it would be /public_html/another_directory/etc/photos/

Answer (score 0):

It's more or less common to use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the path of the php file itself regardless of whether it is called directly or included . So in your situation you could write:

```php
if(file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/photos/'.$this->id.'.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "photos" folder at the same level of the class containing your code:

```
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/../photos/".$this->id.".jpg") ){ 

//

}
```

Comment: i have this structure:  /classes/class.php    and  /photos

Answer (score 0):

dirname(**FILE**) = "../"

dirname(dirname(**FILE**)) = "../../"

dirname(dirname(dirname(**FILE**))) = "../../../"

U can try its.